# How to import/transform unstructured CSV file into SQL table using SSIS

Tags: csv, ssis

I've a .CSV file which comes exported from a 3rd party system in a format as below:

[image]

The CSV file is a single report containing multiple datasets. Every dataset starts with its own column header (time, name, address etc) with blank rows between the next dataset.

I want to extract this data into SQL Sever table using SSIS, but the problem is in the first data set 'Time' column falls into ColB and in the second dataset 'Time' column changes the column position (ColA) each time in single report and there are blank rows in between the data sets. The header (ColA, ColB...) are the column header when CSV is viewed in EXCEL.

How this can be achieved using SSIS?

Comment: You're going to need to use a Script Component/Task to process the data. Either a Script Task to preprocess the source file and generate a new one that is more tabular in nature. Or a Script Component that basically does all of that in memory and emits it as buffers to the data flow

Comment: Thank you! @billinkc - With your direction I was able to utilize the script component to convert  CSV to into a correct tabular form.